# register hive udf in scala - java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: s3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to register a udf in scala spark like this where registering the following udf works in hive `create temporary function udf_parallax as 'com.abc.edw.hww.etl.udf.parallax.ParallaxHiveHash' USING JAR 's3://bx-analytics-softwares/gdpr_hive_udfs/gdpr-hive-udfs-hadoop.jar'`

```
val sparkSess = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Opens")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .config("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").getOrCreate()
sparkSess.sql("""create temporary function udf_parallax as 'com.abc.edw.hww.etl.udf.parallax.ParallaxHiveHash' USING JAR 's3://bx-analytics-softwares/gdpr_hive_udfs/gdpr-hive-udfs-hadoop.jar'""");
```

I get an error saying 
`Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: s3`

Would like to know if I have to set something in config or anything else , I have just started learning.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add this **gdpr-hive-udfs-hadoop.jar** as an external jar to your project and then do this to register the udf:

```
val sqlContext = sparkSess.sqlContext
val udf_parallax = sqlContext.udf .register("udf_parallax", com.abc.edw.hww.etl.udf.parallax.ParallaxHiveHash _)
```

**Update:**

1.If your hive is running on remote server:

```
  val sparkSession= SparkSession.builder()
                        .appName("Opens")
                        .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://METASTORE:9083")
                        .config("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
                        .enableHiveSupport()
                        .getOrCreate()

sparkSession.sql("""create temporary function udf_parallax as 'com.abc.edw.hww.etl.udf.parallax.ParallaxHiveHash' USING JAR 's3://bx-analytics-softwares/gdpr_hive_udfs/gdpr-hive-udfs-hadoop.jar'""");
```

2.If hive is not running on remote server:

Copy the **hive-site.xml** from your **/hive/conf/** directory  to **/spark/conf/** directory and create the ***SparkSession*** as you have mentioned in the question

Comment: I am doing this using qubole where I don't have access to the jar. I need to have some credentials or download this locally somehow in order to do it.

Comment: Hive allows to use it directly. And I seem to be using the same query in Hive.

Comment: As I'm seeing the jar location you are accessing jar from amazon S3. And in order to access those you need to set some properties  [link](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_s3.html). And about hive there must be properties like **fs.s3a.access.key** and **fs.s3a.secret.key** set in **hdfs-site.xml and hive-site.xml** .